# Excel Index Match Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match, conditional-statements

I have to write an Index & Match excel formula, containing multiple criteria!

I have 2 tables:
[image: Table]

My formula should have the following structure:
if Mercedes exists in the first column and Mercedes exists in the fifth column and 
if the code in the second column matches the code in the sixth column
then take the cost from the seventh column and put it in the fourth empty column:
[image]

If both conditions not met, then insert 0. 
[image: FORD 15 0]

It worked when I used Index & Match with 1 criterion, as seen in the above table:

```
=(INDEX($G$2:$G$4,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$6,0),0))
```

G is cost column, E2 is value in the second brand column and A is, of course, the first brand column. 
To add multiple criteria I have tried:

```
=INDEX(G2:G6,MATCH(1,(A2=A2:A4)*(E2=E2:E4),0))
```

It does not work! (returns N/A)

Could you please tell me where I am wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try matching with a combined formula: (assumes E and F are match terms and A and B are the array to match within, with C providing output)

```
{=Index(C:C,Match(E1&F1,A:A&B:B,0))}
```

Use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to utilize the array

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Cyril! I edited the formula accordingly but it returns an error (#Value)!

Comment: @RobertC when in the cell with the formula reading `=Index(C:C,Match(E1&F1,A:A&B:B,0))` press ctrl+shift+enter and the formula will become an array (adds curly braces), where your formula will, after the fact, look like `{=Index(C:C,Match(E1&F1,A:A&B:B,0))}`.

Comment: this is the correct formula:
=INDEX($G$2:$G$6,MATCH(A2&B2,INDEX($E$2:$E$6&$F$2:$F$6,),0))

Comment: When concatenating columns like this it's wise to include a separating character, to avoid data like "cat" & "2" and "ca" & "t2" producing ambiguous results.

Comment: @RobertC Chris didn't tag you, but he has a good point.  Tagging you to ensure you can see this