# Why am I getting wrong result from Index Match formula?

Tags: excel-formula, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I want to get the specific SYMBOL and DATE but I'm getting wrong result

the formula that i use is

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(K2,A:A)*(B:B=L2),0)
```

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you could edit your question to include the formula (in text, not image).  Thanks!

Comment: my bad, formula is in the description already

Comment: I guess you should include another Match in your second argument and 0 as type of match in your match argument = INDEX(F:F, MATCH(K2, A:A,0) *MATCH(L2, B:B, 0))

Comment: only left two known criteria the Symbol and date..

Comment: @12Rev79 How would that work? How does multiplying the two Match results get the correct results? You may want to think that through a bit more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Index Match Multiple Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484346/excel-index-match-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Index_Match]

This what I have tried

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(L2,B:B,0))
```

Comment: That will not match the symbol, though, will it? It will just return the price for the first row with that date, regardles of symbol.

Comment: Is there a way if i have a lot of diferent symbols in A, not only ACEN,

Comment: `=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(1,(K2=A:A)*(B:B=L2),0))` is this what you're trying? When multiplying two conditions the TRUE and FALSE values in the array are changed into 1 and 0. Matching for 1 would get the first match where condition 1 and 2 are both TRUE (1*1) all containing a false would return 0 since the values are then multiplied by 0.

Comment: or may be you could try like this as will =FILTER(FILTER(A1:F23,B1:B23<>"",""),{1,1,0,0,0,1})

Comment: @P.b the result is "#N/A"

Comment: @12rev79 not this one

Comment: @msmavie what have you tried the formula did P.b is working can you give us which error occurs?

Comment: i have updated the image , i think i have problem matching for dates

Comment: i guess its helpful if you can share your file  or number of rows tabulated instead of image

Comment: The formula I suggested needs to be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` in older Excel versions to behave as array-formula.

Answer (score 1):

Since the the data is from .csv file the DATE column needs to be converted in order to get accurate results for index match, “convert text to columns” format “MM/DD/YYYY”